# CMake 2.8.10 installation for mac os x fails creating symlinks

Tags: macos, cmake

I am updating Cmake in my Mac Book pro with OS X Lion 10.7.5. The old version of Cmake is 2.8.8 and the new one is 2.8.10. When I run almost to the end of the installation process, the installer prompts 
for creating a Symlink to /usr/bin of several tools. After click on continue, the installer throws an exception telling that couldn't create symlinks. Previously of the process,  I've moved to trash the old version of Cmake and then using finder I got nothing more files of Cmake on the machine. Any idea how Can I complete the installation succesfully?

Answer (score 6):

In my case, attempting to install cmake 2.8.12 on OSX 10.8.5 failed. The cmake-2.8.12.2-Darwin-universal.dmg installer downloaded directly from cmake.org would hang while running the post install scripts. I found and removed all the symlinks described by willyMon, but it still would hang, requiring me to resort to ps + kill to unhang the installer.

For me, installing via brew did the trick:

```
brew install cmake
```

It installed 2.8.12.2 in /usr/local/bin without a hitch.

Comment: This solution fits the best and saved hours of work! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Opening the Applications folder in a terminal

```
cd /
cd Applications/
```

then doing:

```
sudo bash
CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake-gui
```

Then run from the CMake GUI:
 "Tools->Install For Command Line Use"

works OK for me.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, after looking in deep for this error, I found that I missed some simple detail and this was the key to solve the problem. The Cpack installer of Cmake 2.8.10.1 try to create symbolic links to this files:

-cmake-gui
-cmakexbuild
-cmake
-cpack
-ctest

So, from a terminal I've removed all the previous Symlinks that the older version created, then I ran the installer again and the installation was done succesfully without any errors or warnings.

Comment: Depending on your version of cmake, you also need to remove ccmake.